# Include one row in multiple groupby groups

Tags: python, pandas

I am grouping a time series by hour to perform an operation on each hour of data separately:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = [2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0]
idx = pd.date_range(
    start=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    end=datetime(2019, 1, 1, 2, 30),
    freq=timedelta(minutes=30),
)

s = pd.Series(x, index=idx)
hourly = s.groupby(lambda x: x.hour)

print(s)
print("summed:")
print(hourly.sum())
```

which produces:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00    2
2019-01-01 00:30:00    2
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
2019-01-01 01:30:00    2
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
2019-01-01 02:30:00    0
Freq: 30T, dtype: int64
summed:
0    4
1    6
2    2
dtype: int64
```

As expected.

I now want to know the area under the time series per hour, for which I can use [`numpy.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html):

```
import numpy as np

def series_trapz(series):
    hours = [i.timestamp() / 3600 for i in series.index]
    return np.trapz(series, x=hours)

print("Area under curve")
print(hourly.agg(series_trapz))
```

But for this to work correctly, the boundaries between the groups must appear in *both* groups!

For example, the first group must be:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00    2
2019-01-01 00:30:00    2
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
```

and the second group must be

```
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
2019-01-01 01:30:00    2
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
```

etc.

Is this at all possible using `pandas.groupby`?

Comment: Are `s` always `30 mins` apart?

Comment: This is an example of a more general question, so the specifics shouldn't matter too much. But no, I don't want to make any assumptions about the particulars of the series.

Comment: I wonder what happens if the series does not have data at the hour.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's a good question. I've taken care of that elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could repeat the limit of groups in your serie using [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
r=(s.index.minute==0).astype(int)+1
new_s=s.repeat(r)
print(new_s)

2019-01-01 00:00:00    2
2019-01-01 00:30:00    2
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
2019-01-01 01:30:00    2
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
2019-01-01 02:30:00    0
```

---

Then you could use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html):

```
groups=(new_s.index.to_series().shift(-1,fill_value=0).dt.minute!=0).cumsum()
for i,group in new_s.groupby(groups):
    print(group)
    print('-'*50)

Name: col1, dtype: int64
2019-01-01 00:00:00    2
2019-01-01 00:30:00    2
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
Name: col1, dtype: int64
--------------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 01:00:00    4
2019-01-01 01:30:00    2
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
--------------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 02:00:00    2
2019-01-01 02:30:00    0
Name: col1, dtype: int64
--------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that I have your `np.trapz` logic completely correct here, but I think you can probably get what you want with `.rolling(..., closed="both")` so that the endpoints of the intervals are always included:

```
In [366]: s.rolling("1H", closed="both").apply(np.trapz).iloc[::2]
Out[366]:
2019-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2019-01-01 01:00:00    5.0
2019-01-01 02:00:00    5.0
Freq: 60T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Rolling doesn't aggregate, so it's not a general solution to this problem. (What if the times are uneven for example?)

Comment: @LondonRob `rolling('1H')` should work even for uneven time.

Comment: Yeah, with the time-based `rolling` settings you should be fine (though with the index count-based approach you're correct).

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, but the part about `iloc[::2]` which this answer depends on fails if there are different number of observations between the hourly boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this can be solved manually with `rolling`:

```
hours = np.unique(s.index.floor('H'))

# the answer:
(s.add(s.shift())
  .mul(s.index.to_series()
        .diff()
        .dt.total_seconds()
        .div(3600)
      )
   .rolling('1H').sum()[hours]
)
```

Output:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00    NaN
2019-01-01 01:00:00    5.0
2019-01-01 02:00:00    5.0
dtype: float64
```